# How to use .tpl files in zend frame work 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am  a learner in zend framework. I tried [This](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/overview.html) link and its working fine.
Now i want to use .tpl files instead of .phtml files. For that i referred [This](https://github.com/MurgaNikolay/SmartyModule) .
link and i followed all the steps.
    But when i run the project its a null page...! Whats wrong and what did i missed? Or any other way to use .tpl files instead of .phtml files?

The error i am getting is :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (SmartyModule-dev) could not be initialized.

Actually i added "SmartyModule-dev" in Vendor folder

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: No error .When i run it shows blank page

Comment: Put ini_set('display_errors', true); at the beginning of your config/autoload/local.php file

Comment: still blank page...! Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can see log file of errors. And enable all errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: @newage please see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation steps via composer from library's manual

1. Add "murganikolay/smarty-module": "1.0.0" to your composer.json file and run php composer.phar update.
2. Add SmartyModule to your config/application.config.php file under the modules key.

You forgot to add `SmartyModule` to your `config/application.config.php` file

Comment: Actually the mistake is in smarty/module.php.I added namespace and class Module and getAutoloaderConfig() function and it works fine.Your suggestion on displaying error helped me a lot. thank u :) actual upvote is for that solution.